# View session expiration time from database in readable format

Tags: database, mysql, session

I want to see the session expires time in a readable format. The time is stored as an int. Is there a way to see it in a readable format? I couldn't find how Magento is deriving the int.

I tried the following query, which gave me a readable time, but the values didn't seem right.

```
select session_id, FROM_UNIXTIME(session_expires) as time from core_session ORDER BY time asc limit 20;
```

I tried ordering by both `asc` and `desc`, but neither gave values that seemed right. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From line ~239 of

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Session.php
```

you get

```
'session_expires' => Varien_Date::toTimestamp(true) + $this->getLifeTime(),
```

where

```
/**
 * Retrieve session life time
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getLifeTime()
{
    if (is_null($this->_lifeTime)) {
        $configNode = Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin() ?
                'admin/security/session_cookie_lifetime' : 'web/cookie/cookie_lifetime';
        $this->_lifeTime = (int) Mage::getStoreConfig($configNode);

        if ($this->_lifeTime < 60) {
            $this->_lifeTime = ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');
        }

        if ($this->_lifeTime < 60) {
            $this->_lifeTime = 3600; //one hour
        }

        if ($this->_lifeTime > self::SEESION_MAX_COOKIE_LIFETIME) {
            $this->_lifeTime = self::SEESION_MAX_COOKIE_LIFETIME; // 100 years
        }
    }
    return $this->_lifeTime;
}
```

sets time in seconds. It means the value of the saved fields is composed by i.e a timestamp plus 3600 seconds. You should be able to decode the timestamp with [this](http://www.epochconverter.com/) to see the actual date of expiration in a human format.